# Installing both MySQL and MongoDB on a micro EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to measure the performance difference between MongoDB and MySQL. The plan is to install both MongoDB and MySQL on a single EC2 micro instance and make queries.

I'm not really knowledgeable in the field so I wasn't sure if a single micro instance could sustain both databases. Also please feel free to warn me of any impending doom. If SO isn't the right place for this question, I'd like to know where else to go to ask.

Comment: A `micro` instance isn't the best for measuring performance of any database. Given limited (and shared) resources, the outcome on a micro can be rather unpredictable. You definitely don't want to try to compare with both databases running in the same instance as they'll be competing for the same resources. It's not clear how/what you are comparing, but an obvious caveat is that you should adjust your data model to play to the strengths of each database. The [mongodb-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mongodb-user) discussion group might be able to provide more advice.

Comment: Note: step 1 in any advice should be "Don't use AWS micros for performance testing" ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to install both mongo and mysql on the same instance, and as long as you're not testing them simultaneously, it should work.

But you do not want to use a micro to test performance.  There are too many variables outside your control, and any results you get will be useless - run the tests 5 times, and you may end up with wildly varying results.

Remember that micro instances allow you to burst performance briefly, but if you try to take advantage of this for too long, they will get throttled.

Answer (score 1):

Just have an advice... install them both on separate drives if you can. This will keep them from interfering with each other and decreasing performance.